# Non-English letter input/output problem

Tags: babel, font-encodings, input-encodings

I use this for language

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

Sometimes, i need input some special letter, for example Ö. The language setting worked fine before, but today it report error always when I input some special letter.(I do not remember what i changed to the latex code, seems no changes about language setting).

Below are snapshots for two errors.
What is the problem?

[image]

Comment: The `inputenc` approach covers only a number of chars that have been set up: it can't easily do every UTF-8 char. Which ones are giving you problems (`Ö` for example should be fine).

Comment: are you sure that your file is saved in utf-8 encoding (not for example latin1)

Comment: @JosephWright, ö is not fine too...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it is wriiten as utf8 in .tex file

Comment: @postit OK, as David says that suggests an incorrect encoding or similar. Can you make the 'raw' file available using a file sharing system such as DropBox so we can take a look?

Comment: @postit What editor do you use to save your file? Some of them allow choice of encoding 'on the fly'.

Comment: Are you sure the file is in utf8 (the error you show suggests that it is _declared_ as utf8 but is actually in another encoding (as the letters are not being recognised as valid utf8)

Comment: Thanks both of you, the file is generated by runtime program, i need check the program code

Comment: @JosephWright i know the reason, i used xelatex to generate pdf before

Comment: @postit Ah! You shouldn't be loading `inputenc` with XeTeX: I guess you've worked that out.

Comment: @postit Ah! You shouldn't be loading `inputenc` with XeTeX: I guess you've worked that out.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i know the reason, now i changed xelatex to pdflatex to do the compile, everything is fine then

Comment: @JosephWright yes, change to pdflatex now. Thanks!

Comment: you can't use `inputenc` with xelatex (and it is not needed as xelatex uses utf-8 in anycase)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** The OP used `xelatex` for compilation and everything was fine after changing to `pdflatex`. However, I leave my old answer here for archive purposes.

If it worked for that letter before, you probably saved the file with an editor that converted it from utf-8 to some other format.

If it is a new letter you are entering (not `ö`, which should work), you can try adding the letter manually with

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{03B1}{\ensuremath{\alpha}} %% α
```